# Number of irrational coordinates of the circle $x^2+y^2=5$.

Tags: irrational-numbers

It is given in the book by Malcolm Cameron, titled: Mathematics the Truth; that the circle $x^2+y^2=5$ has an infinite number of points with at least one coordinate irrational, but also an infinite number of rational coordinates too.

I cannot understand. Starting with the latter part as only $(\pm 1, \pm 2)$ seem to be only the $4$ points with rational coordinates; rather than an infinite number of rational coordinates.

Similarly for the irrational coordinates, as not clear how an infinite number of such (at least one) coordinates can be there. 
Any such points have to anyway satisfy $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=5, \ a,b\in \mathbb{R}$.

So, how to prove this statement.

I request at least suitable hints in the direction to pursue.

[image]

Comment: *Hint*: make a line of rational slope passing through known rational point $(1,2)$.  Similarly irrationals.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks a lot. Please make an answer. Requesting to get more inputs as well as to avoid errors.

Comment: A strange question ... there infinitely many points on a circle, so how can you think that there would be finite points with rational and finite points with irrational coordinates? What are the coordinates of the other points then? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the point $P=(2,1)$ on the circle. Take **any** line through $P$ with rational gradient:
$$y-1=m(x-2)$$
with $m\in\Bbb Q$. This meets the circle in two points (unless it's the tangent
at $P$), namely $P$ and $Q$ say. Then $Q$ also has rational coordinates.

As an example take $m=2$. Then the line is $y=2x-3$. Substituting in $x^2+y^2=5$
gives
$$x^2+(2x-3)^2=5x^2-12x+9=5.$$
This quadratic has roots $x=2$ and $x=2/5$ leading to $P=(2,1)$ and $Q=(2/5,-11/5)$.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not clear how it proves that there are an infinite number of at least one irrational coordinates.

Comment: That's easy: pick $x$ to be any irrational between $\pm\sqrt5$ and let $y=\sqrt{5-x^2}$. @jiten